# Calculating the analogue of Euler angles/Tait-Bryan angles for dimensions >3

Tags: r, math, rotation, geometry, euler-angles

While trying to answer [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31491228/how-do-i-find-the-angles-between-an-original-and-a-rotated-pca-loadings-matrix/31496434#31496434), the issue of how to calculate Euler angles for dimensions > 3 came up. The `RSpincalc` package has a straightforward `DCM2EA` function for converting a 3d rotation matrix to Euler or Tait-Bryan angles, but this only handles the specific case of 3 dimensions. The [wikipedia page on Euler angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Higher_dimensions) briefly discusses the issue of extending Euler angles to higher dimensions and cites an [Italian paper](http://ansi.altervista.org/) which apparently generalises the method to greater numbers of dimensions. Unfortunately, neither my Italian nor my maths are quite up to taking that paper and creating a usable R function.

My current method, used in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31491228/how-do-i-find-the-angles-between-an-original-and-a-rotated-pca-loadings-matrix/31496434#31496434) is a little cumbersome, to say the least. I use the `Ryacas` package to create a symbolic matrix which is the composite of a series of rotations for an arbitrary number of dimensions. This can then be solved iteratively against a known rotation matrix to find the angles required. It works, but it gets increasingly slow once the number of dimensions is 5 or more.

Is there a better way to achieve this objective, either through implementation of the method in the [Italian paper](http://ansi.altervista.org/) or something else?

Answer (score 2):

There is an interesting paper [here](http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/journal/jmp/13/4/10.1063/1.1666011) from 1972 that addresses the issue of computing N-dimensional Euler angles given an N-dimensional orthogonal matrix (which I assume is what you have). I skimmed the paper and it gives formulas for what you seem to need:

1. The transformation matrix given the N-dimensional Euler angles
2. The N-dimensional Euler angles given the transformation matrix
3. Alternative parameterizations since the equations given in the paper address one particular parameterization, which is common to Euler representations.

I did not try to re-derive and validate their equations but they give explicit formulas so you could implement them for low-dimensions for which you already have answers and see if they agree.

Comment: I won't be able to verify this in the next 7 hours but it's the closest to an answer there's been so I've awarded the bounty.