# how can I retrieve / impute the underlying rotation matrix (rotmat) from psych::principal?

Tags: r, matrix, rotation, pca, psych

I'm using `psych::principal` in another function, with various `rotate` functions passed to `principal`.
(`principal` offers *many* rotation options and passes them on to different other functions).

I need to get the *rotation matrix* that whichever rotation procedure was used found, and implemented.

All of the downstream rotation procedures offer this, but it appears not to be `return()`ed by `principal`.

For example:

```
randomcor <- cor(matrix(data = rnorm(n = 100), nrow = 10))
library(psych)
principalres <- principal(r = randomcor, nfactors = 3, rotate = "none")
unrot.loa <- unclass(principalres$loadings)

principalrot <- principal(r = randomcor, nfactors = 3, rotate = "varimax") # there is no way to retrieve the rot.mat from principal

# but this CAN be done from the underlying varimax!
varimaxres <- varimax(x = unrot.loa)
varimaxres$rotmat # see, THIS is what I want!
```

I am loathe to re-implement all of the rotation procedures from `principal`. 
(Don't repeat yourself, or someone else, as the say).

Does anyone have an idea how:

- I could elegantly, somehow, magically, **retrieve** `rotmat` from `principal()`, though it appears not to return it?
- I could, alternatively, **impute** whichever `rotmat` must have "happened", because I know the *rotated* and *unrotated* loadings?

Comment: the psych package author, William Revelle, just told me that:

> I will add that feature in the next release.  (coming in about 2 weeks).

I'll update the post, once that feature is out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as promised by William Revelle, as of `1.5.8`, `psych` also returns the rotation matrices for factor analyses and principal components analysis.

This solves the problem, continuing the above example:

```
principalrot$rot.mat == varimaxres$rotmat  # it works!
```